# Factoring out asynchronous code involving tornado.gen.Task

Tags: python, mongodb, generator, tornado

I have numerous tornado.web.RequestHandler classes that test for authorized access using id and access key secure cookies. I access mongodb asynchronously with inline callbacks using gen.Task. I am having trouble figuring out a way to factor out the repetitive code because of its asynchronicity. How can I do this?

```
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        id = self.get_secure_cookie('id', None)
        accesskey = self.get_secure_cookie('accesskey', None)
        if not id or not accesskey:
            self.redirect('/a_public_area')
            return
        try:
            # convert to bson id format to access mongodb
            bson.objectid.ObjectId(id)
        except:
            # if not valid object id
            self.redirect('/a_public_area')
            return
        found_id, error = yield gen.Task(asyncmong_client_inst.collection.find_one, 
            {'_id': id, 'accesskey': accesskey}, fields={'_id': 1})
        if error['error']:
            raise HTTPError(500)
            return
        if not found_id[0]:
            self.redirect('/a_public_area')
            return

        # real business code follows
```

I would like to factor the above into a function that yields perhaps an HTTP status code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tornado has decorator `@tornado.web.authenticated`. Let's use it.

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
   def get_login_url(self):
        return u"/a_public_area"

    @gen.engine #Not sure about this step
    def get_current_user(self):
        id = self.get_secure_cookie('id', None)
        accesskey = self.get_secure_cookie('accesskey', None)
        if not id or not accesskey:
            return False

        #Are you sure need this? 
        try:
            # convert to bson id format to access mongodb
            bson.objectid.ObjectId(id)
        except:
            # if not valid object id
            return False

        #I believe that you don't need asynchronous mongo on auth query, so if it's not working - replace it with sync call
        found_id, error = yield gen.Task(asyncmong_client_inst.collection.find_one, 
            {'_id': id, 'accesskey': accesskey}, fields={'_id': 1})

        if error['error']:
            raise HTTPError(500)

        if not found_id[0]:
            return False

        return found_id


class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        # real business code follows
```

Using `gen` everywhere - not good practice. It can turn this world in big spaghetti. Think about it.

Comment: Wow, that's very elegant of tornado to include this. Why is using gen everywhere not good practice? I thought a bunch of nested callbacks would be worse.

Comment: I was meaning, that `gen` simplifies async calls, and makes developer to want to use anywhere. But for example on authentication check it will not give any benefits, and will slow down application a little - it's better to use synchronous call here.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps a decorator (not tested or anything, just some ideas)

```
def sanitize(fn):
    def _sanitize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.get_secure_cookie('id', None)
        accesskey = self.get_secure_cookie('accesskey', None)
        if not id or not accesskey:
            self.redirect('/a_public_area')
            return
        try:
            # convert to bson id format to access mongodb
            bson.objectid.ObjectId(id)
        except:
            # if not valid object id
            self.redirect('/a_public_area')
            return
        return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return _sanitize
```

dunno if you can make the check_errors work with the business logic..but maybe..

```
def check_errors(fn):
   def _check_errors(*args, **kwargs)
      found_id, error = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      if error['error']:
         raise HTTPError(500)
         return
      if not found_id[0]:
         self.redirect('/a_public_area')
         return
   return _check_errors
```

then

```
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    @sanitize
    @check_errors #..O.o decorators
    def get(self):
        found_id, error = yield gen.Task(asyncmong_client_inst.collection.find_one, 
              {'_id': id, 'accesskey': accesskey}, fields={'_id': 1})
        return found_id, error
```

Comment: I wasn't that familiar with decorators before, but they seem very useful! I found this post which also helps me out a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848907/authentication-using-cookie-key-with-asynchronous-callback?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to address this general problem with gen.Task, which is that factoring out code is either impossible or extremely clumsy.

You can only do "yield gen.Task(...)" within the get() or post() method.  If you want to have get() call another function foo(), and do the work in foo(), well: You can't, unless you want to write everything as a generator and chain them together in some unwieldy way. As your project gets bigger, this is going to be a huge problem.

This is a much better alternative: https://github.com/mopub/greenlet-tornado

We used this to convert a large synchronous codebase to Tornado, with almost no changes.